# Combinatorics question: Suppose you play a game of cards in which only 5 cards are dealt from a standard 52 deck....

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games, poker

Suppose you play a game of cards in which only 5 cards are dealt from a standard 52 deck. How many ways are there to obtain at least 3 cards of the same suit?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Consider solving for just one suit and then multiply your answer by 4. Ask yourself why doing this works in this case.